# Undefined variable : error in login page

Tags: php

is there any way to fix undefined variable on login page? I can't solve it by refering the php manual.What can I do to fix the ($error).Here is my login script on the top of html page and undefined variable code:

```
<?php

     include("dbconnect.php");

     if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
          session_start();
     }

     if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']=='yes'){
          // logged in
          header("location: index.html");
          exit();
     }

     /* check to see if user attempted logging in */
     if($_GET["atmpt"] != NULL){
          if($_GET["atmpt"] == 2){
          // forgotten password
          $error .= "Did you forget your password?<br>";
     }

     /* get username and password */
     $username = $_POST["username"];
     $password = $_POST["password"];

     /* MySQL Injection prevention */
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes($username));
     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes($password));

     /* check for user in database */
     $query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
     $count = $result->num_rows;
     if($count > 0){
          //successfully logged in
          $_SESSION['username']=$username;
          $_SESSION['loggedin']='yes';
          header("Location: index.html");
          exit();
     } else {
          // Login Failed
          $error .=  "Wrong Username or Password";
          $_SESSION['loggedin']='no';
          $atmpt = 2;
     }
} else {
     $atmpt = 1;
}

?>
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home/tz005/public_html/COMP1687/login.php on line 111

```
<span><?php echo($error) ?></span>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- irrelevant as doesn't affect the output with or without parenthesis in this case and is not the cause of the original error

Comment: where you are printing this value? post full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize $error first.

Put  `$error='';` above `$error .= "Did you forget your password?<br>";`

It's now trying to concatenate the current value value of error with "Did you forget your password?
" and since there is now current value for error since it isn't initialized or assigned with another value before, and hence throws and undefined variable error.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to fix undefined variable on login page?

Yes. Your undefined variable is `$error`, so at the top of your script, give it a default value:

```
$error = '';
```

Comment: i dont think it needs to be initialized :??

Comment: @user790454 unfortunately you'd be wrong. The reason the OP is getting this error is because he is trying to echo its contents when it doesn't exist. Initializing the variable with a default value will mean that if no errors are assigned, that output statement will just output the blank/default value. Of course there are better ways to deal with this scenario, but that's a different story.

Comment: yeah in that case it has to be defined

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <?php

 include("dbconnect.php");

 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
 }

 if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']=='yes'){
      // logged in
      header("location: index.html");
      exit();
 }

 /* check to see if user attempted logging in */
 if($_GET["atmpt"] != NULL){
      if($_GET["atmpt"] == 2){
      // forgotten password
      $error = "Did you forget your password?<br>";
 }
 else
 {
 $error = "";
 }

 /* get username and password */
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];

 /* MySQL Injection prevention */
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes($username));
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, stripslashes($password));

 /* check for user in database */
 $query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
 $count = $result->num_rows;
 if($count > 0){
      //successfully logged in
      $_SESSION['username']=$username;
      $_SESSION['loggedin']='yes';
      header("Location: index.html");
      exit();
 } else {
      // Login Failed
      $error .=  "Wrong Username or Password";
      $_SESSION['loggedin']='no';
      $atmpt = 2;
       }
  } else {
  $atmpt = 1;
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would [clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236811/1767316) using the following command in terminal:
`php artisan config:cache`