# Difference between "php artisan config:cache" and "php artisan cache:clear" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching

In Laravel have noticed there is two way to clear the cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:cache
```

However i realized only the second one working properly when changing the localization, adding laravel/passport package and etc..

What is their difference ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`php artisan cache:clear` - Flush the application cache

`php artisan config:cache` - Create a cache file for faster configuration loading. 
This is for configuration cache. This command will clear the configuration cache before it creates. [More details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching)

`php artisan config:clear` - Remove the configuration cache file

Comment: so we got two type of cache in Laravel ? one for application and one for configuration ?

Comment: @ghazyy yes, application cache & configuration cache

Comment: Do we need to apply one of these when generating a new APP_KEY on production? If so, which one? I have a `403 | Invalid signature` error when using Email Verification

Comment: there are also route cache and view cache..

Answer (score 3):

BTW there are also

```
php artisan route:cache
```

and

```
php artisan route:clear
```

commands available which create and clear route cache respectively. And many others similar commands I found in the [Laravel Artisan Cache Commands Explained](https://dev.to/kenfai/laravel-artisan-cache-commands-explained-41e1) article.

Comment: * just to add to the confusion